# Heroku DIscord.js Typescript - bot works but build is stuck on pending

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku, discord.js

So I deployed my Discord.js (written with TypeScript) bot to Heroku, the bot works but build is stuck as pending.  Below is Heroku build log:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack

-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app

-----> Node.js app detected



       

-----> Creating runtime environment

       

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error

       NODE_VERBOSE=false

       NODE_ENV=production

       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true

       

-----> Installing binaries

       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified

       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       

       Resolving node version 14.x...

       Downloading and installing node 14.16.1...

       Using default npm version: 6.14.12

       

-----> Installing dependencies

       Installing node modules

       

       > mybot@1.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_525987f7

       > tsc

       

       added 20 packages in 6.722s

       

-----> Build

       Running build

       

       > mybot@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_525987f7

       > node dist/main.js

       

       Connected
```

"Connected" is a console log msg I send when the bot successfully connects.

Here are my scripts from package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc -w",
    "postinstall": "tsc",
    "start": "node dist/main.js",
    "start-dev": "nodemon dist/main.js",
    "build": "node dist/main.js"
  },
```

So what is going on here? The bot is fully functional but the build is stuck as pending

EDIT: Ok so after like 1 hour the build timed out. But I managed to get it all working.
First I changed my package.json scripts to this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/main.js",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
```

Then I created a Procfile in the root directory with
`worker: npm start`
And that fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend debugging the websocket connections and check where it gets timed out.
to do so you may use the following :

```js
<client>.on("debug", (debug) => { 
console.log(debug)
});
```

Furthermore Heroku is not suited for bots using heavy adapters/dependencies such as `ffmpeg`, `better-sqlite-3`, `opus`, etc. Therefore if you are unable to determine what breaks the connection consider switching hosts.

Comment: It was an issue with Procfile, well, rather not having one, as I wrote in my edit, everything works fine now. And yeah I'm aware heroku is not the best option for hosting bots but all my bot does is fetch data from endpoints and display it, i don't need much for that.